# Why does Xcode Crash when filter RealmSwift with variable?

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I've tested this several times, and I keep getting the same result that does not make sense to me.

I'm wanting to filter the Stuff for a particular week. `Stuff` is a realm object and `week` is an integer. If the filter includes an integer, it works.

```
let result = realm.objects(Stuff.self).filter("week < 14")
```

However, the week will not be known beforehand, so the correct value of week is stored in a variable. Both of the following fail by crashing Xcode.

```
let compareweek = 14
let query = NSPredicate(format: "week < %@", compareweek)
let result = realm.objects(Stuff.self).filter(query)

let compareweek = 14
let result = realm.objects(Stuff.self).filter("week < compareweek")
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Instead of using `%@`, use `%d` to represent an Integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is about formatting the `NSPredicate`. If you go to [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html), you can see:

> The format string supports printf-style format specifiers such as %x
>   (see [Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)). Two important format specifiers are
>   %@ and %K.
>
> - %@ is a var arg substitution for an **object value** — often a string,
>     number, or date.

This mean that you should pass to `NSPredicate` not `Int` but `NSNumber` (more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)).

```
let compareweek: NSNumber = 14
let query = NSPredicate(format: "week < %@", compareweek)
let result = realm.objects(Stuff.self).filter(query)
```

---

The simplest solution is provided by @Scriptable:

> Instead of using `%@`, use `%d` to represent an Integer.

So, this also works fine:

```
let compareweek = 14
let query = NSPredicate(format: "week < %d", compareweek)
let result = realm.objects(Stuff.self).filter(query)
```

Comment: We should try to stick to Swift types where possible. It is much better to use Int in Swift than NSNumber.

Comment: @Scriptable, you are right. this is much better. i updated my answer with you notes. thanks.